# After updating an older computer from v12 to v14 it is very slow

Tags: 14.04

Everything is slowed WAY down - 5 to 10 seconds just to open something from the task bar. Then it slowly fades in. Totally destroyed my confidence in Ubuntu as a viable alternative to WinXp. This has been an ongoing thing with Linux actually being a operating system for normal people and not just for geeks. Until A normal non geek can actually just install a working version without having to resort to the command line to actually get stuff to work. It will not be used by anyone other than the geeks that like to play around with the OS. I wanted to give this system to a NORMAL person ( non geek) but now - I will just have spend another couple of hours trying to reinstall the older v12 or to go back to Windows because they don't have the technical know how to jump through the hoops to get Ubuntu to actually work. They don't want to 'play' with the OS, they just want to run fairly standard programs.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is likely not the best solution for an older computer as Unity, it's desktop environment is primarily designed for more recent computers. Xubuntu is the better solution for older computers, it used XFCE which is a much lighter desktop environment. It can be found at [http://xubuntu.org](http://xubuntu.org/).

For reference, Ubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome and Kubuntu generally are not suitable for older systems as Unity (Ubuntu), Gnome (Ubuntu Gnome) and to a lesser extent KDE (Kubuntu) desktop environments take up more system resources. Where as Xubuntu and Lubuntu will usually run well as XFCE (Xubuntu) and LXDE (Lubuntu) take up far less system resources but are not as flashy either.

My suggestion is that is your system supports PAE then Xubuntu will likely be ideal. If the Xubuntu liveCD will not boot, your system likely does not support PAE so try Lubuntu.